# What are the normalized entries called on the table of contents of thefreedictionary?

Tags: word-request, terminology

For example, these multi-word expressions or lexical units can be listed in their [very base forms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+one%27s+mark+on) on thefreedictionary.com:

```
leave one's mark
leave mark on
develop from
develop from someone
develop
fight shy of
fight shy of something
be fighting shy of doing something
be out of one's shell
```

instead of any of their variations like the following:

```
leave his mark
left mark on
developing from
developed from a painfully shy girl 
developed
fighting shy of
fight shy of controversy
was fighting shy of cheating
is out of your shell
```

I know that they are not the idioms(as idioms may include possessive pronouns), stems(as stems include subwords), lemmas(as lemmas also include pronouns), or lexemes(also include pronouns; and 'is' and 'be' are two different lexemes) of their inflections or variations.

I wonder if such a very base form has a terminology? I want to **normalize** the variations into their most base units. Possessive pronouns should become forms like "one's" which cannot be further **normalized**.

Comment: The thefreedictionary.com includes them, and I see them listed on the Full Browser section. @Lambie

Comment: Those are just called idioms: look at the name of the URL: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+(one%27s)+mark These are called **idioms** or **idiomatic expressions**.

Comment: @Lambie I differ. Look at the `Full browser` part.

Comment: You differ? What does that mean: I differ??

Comment: The window has these categories: Dictionary
Thesaurus/Medical/Dictionary/Legal Dictionary/Financial Dictionary/Acronyms/Idioms/Encyclopedia
Wikipedia What you are calling basic forms are known as **idioms**.

Comment: That "full browser" thing is the main word followed by the idioms containing the word, as I have explained.

Comment: For the `I differ` expression, please refer to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1631943609556795392). @Lambie I think Judea Pearl means something like `I beg to differ`.

Comment: We say in English: I disagree [with you] and for differ: My answer differs from yours. We differ in our response to the crisis. But not: I differ. Anyway, I have now explained twice that these are idioms connected to a main base word. What else do you need? That Tweet is saying: I differ **here**. where here means in this regard. Without an object, it does not work.

Comment: `Put your best foot forward` and `In over your head` can count as idioms but I want to convert them to `Put one's best foot forward` and `In over one's head`.

Comment: So, do it. Idioms are  usually given in a base form but one can always change the pronouns. What is the problem??  You are not **converting anything**. You are merely adopting the idiom to the subject/speaker. Look, I feel like you are using me and arguing with what is basic standard English which I am trying to communicate to you. And going on and one, essentially about what is a non-thing.

Comment: I would not regard an expression using "one" as basic or normalised, but as *abstract*. A dictionary which is intended to be readable may avoid these forms as being more difficult for some users to understand.

Comment: @Peter I wonder if there is an appropriate normalized form for possessive pronouns like "our", "your", "his"?

Comment: Use "one's" as the possessive. "Oneself" is also a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "lemmas".  A lemma is the form of a word or phrase that is listed as the headword in a dictionary.

I'm not sure what you mean by "lemmas include pronouns".  Yes,  "He" is a lemma, as is "His" and "Him" (in most dictionaries). That is irrelevant to whether or not "Leave his mark" is a lemma in this particular dictionary.

There is no single or standard process of lemmatization. The Free Dictionary uses "one" or "one's" instead of gendered pronouns, and "somebody" or "something" instead of anything more specific, when a noun phrase is required by the idiom, but any could be used.  It uses the bare infinitive form of verbs, it drops the subject if it is not a fixed part of the idiom.

Those are sensible, but not universal processes for lemmatization of a phrase or idiom.

Comment: I have not found any rules or standards for lemmatization of a phrase or idiom

Comment: That is because there are not rules or standards for the lemmatization of a phrase or idiom.  But you can infer the methods that a dictionary is using from the evidence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any specific term that will cover exactly what you want, but you might try "[normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting))" or "[canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form)" (which have similar meanings in logic, computer science, etc.). I think that those terms are different from what you want but somewhat close. You might have better luck asking on the [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) sites.

(You may want to edit your examples to make them clearer. For example, the 6th entry in each list is "developed", so I don't know why you'd want the first "instead of" the second. I tried my best to understand what you were looking for.)

Comment: I have updated my question and am sorry for the mistake I made in the 6th entry.