# Is "I differ" idiomatic?

Tags: verbs

In [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334063/what-are-the-entries-called-on-the-table-of-contents-of-a-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment633813_334063) I was asked to explain the expression "I differ" which I learned from [this context](https://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1631943609556795392). I don't know if just saying "I differ" is enough to express disagreement?

> I differ here. Both humans and amoebas are programmed to survive, true, but humans are born with an innate template for building causal models of their environments, which explains the reward-neutral curiosity of babies in the crib. https://t.co/dxqdoqvpOm— Judea Pearl (@yudapearl) [March 4, 2023](https://twitter.com/yudapearl/status/1631943609556795392?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries? What do you mean by 'idiomatiic'?

Comment: I mean if it is acceptable in spoken English?

Comment: It is acceptable and also formal.

Comment: In very formal British English, people may say (to express polite disagreement with something just said) 'I beg to differ', and if after an argument, no agreement can be reached, people may say 'we will have to agree to differ'.

Comment: I must have heard and used *I beg to differ* thousands of times. But I'm quite sure I've never in my life heard anyone come out with the 2-word utterance ***I differ***. That form is *definitely* unidiomatic, though I see nothing particularly unusual about OP's cited written instance ***I differ here***.

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers on that. While it seems fine and natural as part of a larger sentence (e.g. "*Mary and **I differ** in our views of...*"), in the specific quote I would argue it is not idiomatic. Grammatical, yes, but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20differ%2C%20I%20beg%20to%20differ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "I differ" was very much more common in writing than "I beg to differ" in the early part of the 19th century, but has been in steady decline since then. The latter only overtook the former in 2010.

That said, I would expect that "I beg to differ" is much more common in formal spoken English, and the rise we see in its written usage is a recent crossover from spoken to written English, to compensate for the decline in popularity of "I differ".

So, "I differ" is fine in formal written English, though somewhat old fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'll join with @FumbleFingers to say that I **do not** think this is an idiomatic use of the word *differ*. I'll offer up an alternative and then spend some time discussing the way *differ* is most commonly used.

### Alternatives to and problems with "I differ"

I would suggest you use the idiom ***I beg to differ***; this is a very common formal phrase to indicate disagreement.

The phrase *I differ*, while not ungrammatical, is unidiomatic the same way *I argue* or *I dispute* are unidiomatic. *Disagreeing* is something that, for the purposes of idiomaticity, you can do alone: there's nothing unidiomatic about the sentence *I disagree*. However, if you *argue* or *dispute* or ***differ*** you **must make it clear *how*, *with what*, or *with whom* you doing these things**. The phrase *I differ* has the additional problem that, in isolation, it's not clear which sense is meant: are you saying you disagree or that you are in some way different? If the former, the missing information is *from whom*? If the latter, *how*?

There are three major senses of *differ*:

1. To be different; to have a distinguishing characteristic
2. To have a different opinion; to disagree
3. To argue, quarrel, or express disagreement.

It's the third sense (to my ear, a somewhat dated sense) which gave rise to the idiom *I beg to differ*. The literal meaning is "I hope you'll let me argue with you on this point."

### Using Differ

*Differ* parallels *disagree* in its reliance on **prepositions**: When the subject is an individual object, person, or type, *differ* is almost always used with a proposition--usually *from*, or, more rarely, *with* or *about*. This applies to all of its most common senses (both those to do with *having distinction* and those to do with *disagreeing*):

> Every leaf on a tree *differs* **from** its neighbors in subtle ways. 
> I *differ* **from** some of my friends as to how we ought to make this happen. 
> Let us join hands with those who *differ* **with** us. 
> This specimen *differs* wildly **from** the others we have collected.

Compare

> I *disagree* **with** what you've just said.

When applied to a group (thank you @terdon for the example) we tend to either (A) not use a preposition to indicate what is different from what; or (B) use some other phrase to indicate that the difference exists among elements of the collection (this is easier to see with an example):

> Mary and I *differ* about where her part of the fence ends and mine begins. 
> Brown and white sugar don't *differ* much **from one another** in taste. 
> My wife and I get along great! We rarely *differ*.

Hopefully that helps!